# libcurl or cURL not working OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, curl

Before I start let me say I have uninstalled, reinstalled, compiled from source, used macports and generally tried for the last 6 hours to get curl working on my Mac OSX Mavericks but I still haven't come right.

If I try do anything with curl I get this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 8.0.0 or later, but     libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

However, if I check my curl I don't see anything wrong.

```
$ which curl
/opt/local/bin/curl

$ otool -L /opt/local/bin/curl
/opt/local/bin/curl:
    /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.9.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.3.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55471.14.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.14.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

$ otool -L /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.14.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55471.14.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.9.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.3.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

My curl library is version 8.0.0 I did a `locate libcurl.4.dylib | xargs otool -L` and this showed that the only version 7.0.0 of curl I have exists within the MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib folder and it is not symlinked from anywhere.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use curl shipped with Mavericks and libcurl shipped with XCode?

Comment: Doesn't come with HTTPS support. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you.

1. I suggest you to check the libcurl under  `/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`. If it is version 7.0.0, move it to another name and make a link to your `/opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`. But this may potentially affect the behaviors of some applications that use libcurl, thus not recommended.
2. Or better, check possible configurations by running `brew options formula-name` and then run`brew install formular-name --with-brewed-curl` if there is such options.
3. You can build from source code and configure the `LIBCURL_CFLAGS` and `LIBCURL_LIBS` if 2 does not work.

I have not tried either 2 or 3. <del>You can read this article here http://www.dreamhack.it/?p=95.</del>

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One solution was provided in http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-10/0072.html

The idea is to make a static build of curl and then paste it to you /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin/. Briefly:

1. ~$ `xcode-select --install`
2. Download the latest version of curl from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
3. cd to the directory and run
   ~$ `./configure --disable-shared --with-darwinssl --enable-threaded-resolver`
   ~$ `` make -j `sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu_max` ``
4. Copy the compiled curl, which is located in `./src/curl` to your `/usr/bin/`

Note: in the `make` command the sign "`" is indeed back quote, not single quote.