# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib curl SSL error

Tags: macos, unix, git, ssl, curl

I'm not sure what happened to my system but I am having an issue with dyld/curl, affecting my overall computer performance. I am on Yosemite.

I have a feeling it's the Conda openssl. How do I just link to the normal os X openssl?

If I try to use curl ssl (for example, to install rvm with the command:

```
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
```

And I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gpg
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
(23) Failed writing body
```

I've taken a [look at](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-10/0072.html) [these](https://www.dreamhack.it/?p=95) [threads](https://superuser.com/questions/759713/libcurl-or-curl-not-working-osx-mavericks) but my problem seems different. Can someone help me out? It seems like I might need to create a link but I don't know what that means or how to make one.

`which curl` gives:

```
/opt/local/bin/curl
```

`curl --version` gives:

```
curl 7.39.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0) libcurl/7.39.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1j zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29
```

git version is `2.1.3`

`which openssl` gives

```
`//anaconda/bin/openssl`
```

`Which git` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Comment: Which git returns: /usr/local/bin/git I am on Yosemite

Comment: Right. It's added.

Answer (score 0):

Your `which curl` returns this:

```
/opt/local/bin/curl
```

Which is odd, since `curl` is not really a magical program that needs to be installed in the `/opt/` directory and `which curl` on a standard Mac OS X install should be here:

```
/usr/bin/curl
```

My guess is the version of `curl` installed in `/opt/local/bin/` is built against another system architecture (32 bit?) but the core system `/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib` stuff is set for 64 bit.

The quickest/safest thing to do if you want to instal Ruby via the method you describe is to explicitly call the core Mac OS X install like this:

```
/usr/bin/curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
```

But that said, if I were you [I would follow the basic instructions on this RVM install page](https://rvm.io/rvm/security) here to get it up and running. Then again, it seems like you have files tossed all over your install conflicting with each other so perhaps the `/usr/bin/curl` method is the safest? Seems that way to me.

Comment: The lipo command can tell you the architectures in the /usr/local/bin/curl binary for sure. JakeGould is right in that you don't need that since osx has it. Try 'brew removel curl'.