# Git returns “dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib” error on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, git

I'm on Mac OS 10.6. I did some weird stuff trying to run a Jekyll and Node.js based site locally, which didn't work, and I'm now having problems with basic git functionality. The earlier process involved installing Homebrew and upgrading Ruby.

When I run `git pull` from within a repository, I get

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
>     Referenced from: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https
>     Reason: Incompatible library version: git-remote-https requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 6.0.0

I tried [a suggestion from a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/873373/76575), and when I entered `which curl` , I got `/usr/bin/curl`.

I thought perhaps upgrading git might help, so I did `brew install git` and got [the following (see below)](http://pastebin.com/5fMUYB3W), which seemed to indicate that I'm on the current version (2.8.1). However after that, `git --version` returns `git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26)`.

No idea what to do next. How can I get git working again?

```
Warning: You are using OS X 10.6.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
==> Downloading https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.8.1.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-2.8.1.tar.xz
==> make install prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.8.1 sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc CC
Last 15 lines from /Users/mikeeng/Library/Logs/Homebrew/git/01.make:
    sed -e '1{' \
        -e '    s|#!.*perl|#!/usr/bin/perl|' \
        -e '    h' \
        -e '    s=.*=use lib (split(/:/, $ENV{GITPERLLIB} || "'"$INSTLIBDIR"'"));=' \
        -e '    H' \
        -e '    x' \
        -e '}' \
        -e 's/@@GIT_VERSION@@/2.8.1/g' \
        git-add--interactive.perl >git-add--interactive+ && \
    chmod +x git-add--interactive+ && \
    mv git-add--interactive+ git-add--interactive
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/config.h', needed by `perl.mak'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [instlibdir] Error 2
make: *** [git-add--interactive] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues

These open issues may also help:
git-annex 6.20160619 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/3228
hg-git 0.8.5 (new formula) https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/2577
git: cannot run gitk https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/115
git-webui 1.2.0 (new formula) https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/1648
cannot install on Mac OSX 10.8.5 ==> Downloading and installing Homebrew... You must: brew install git You must: brew install git Error: Git is unavailable https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/2385
git-gitlab 0.1.0 (new formula) https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/1064
git-stree: added deprecation warning and fixed line order https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/1842
Warning: You are using OS X 10.6.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by uninstalling git. Turns out I had multiple installations in different places, so I had to do:

```
$ which git
```

and then using the path that returned:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /absolute/path/to/git
```

three times until `$ which git` returned nothing. Then I installed [git 1.8.4.2](https://git-osx-installer.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.4.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg)

Then when I ran `$ git`, I was getting:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory
```

But quitting and relaunching Terminal resolved that, and git seems to be working properly now.